# Firebase - Best way to safely check if and value exists

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having a list of E-Mail subscribers and want to add a new one on button click. This should be possible for non-logged-in users. Therefore there need to be a check if this entry is already in the database. As I don't want to expose the full list to the non-logged-in user, how would I check if an E-Mail address already exists without making a fetch GET request that is having rights to access that list with firebase, as the whole code is exposed in the frontend? I'm working with version Web9.

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore, collection, addDoc, getDocs, query, where } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projected: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: "",
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore();

const auth = getAuth(app);
```

Fuction for adding the doc:

```
const addDocument = (dbName, obj) => {
  return addDoc(collection(db, dbName), obj);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Firestore security rules you can break down a `read` rule into `get` and `list` as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations).

In your case you would assign read access to everybody with the `get` rule and deny access to the `list` rule. This way, the unauthenticated users can only fetch a specific document (identified with a specific email address) and verify if this given "entry" is already in the database. They cannot list all the existing entries.

Of course, a user could try many different email addresses but will not be able to directly get the list of all existing entries in the database with one query.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. With `get` it would still send the whole doc to the frontend right? Is there something like the `exists` method that wouldn't allow for sending the whole doc in the security rules but only allow to check if an entry exists without any details about it?

Comment: No this is not possible. But what you can do is to duplicate your data and create a collection with documents containing just one dummy field and an doc id corresponding to the email addresses. Then it's easy to query (just a DocReference) and the end user just sees the mail address and nothing else. In the NoSQL world, you should not be afraid to duplicate data and denormalize your data model.

Comment: Ok, what a pitty. How would I query for only one doc in V9 I don't want to use `getDocs` instead I want to use `getDoc` but this doesn't seem to work with `where` queries. `getDoc(query(collection(db, "newsletterSubscribers"), where("email", "==", "EMAIL_ADDRESS_TO_CHECK"))`?

Comment: If you use the email addresses ad IDs of the doc you don’t need a query. Just use the `getDoc()` method.

Comment: Thanks for this workaround, still is there an option to use `getDoc` with a `where` query?

Comment: "is there an option to use `getDoc` with a where `query`" => No, as detailed in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#getdoc) of `getDoc()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code solution that hopefully helps somebody. The goal has been to check if a single document exists and restrict the database access to check existence. I found only one possible option to do this (Excluding cloud functions). Thanks to @RenaudTarnec answer. There is no way to get a single doc with a query by field value. The only option is to set the id of the document to the specified E-Mail address (value you want to query).

**Code:**

**Check if already subscribed, if not add to database of subscribers:**

```
 const [error, setError] = useState("");
 const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

 const handleSubmit = async (values: { email: string }) => {
        const dbName = "newsletterSubscribers";
        const docId = values.email;
        setMessage("");
        setError("");
    
        const docRef = doc(db, dbName, docId);
        const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
    
        if (docSnap.exists()) {
          // E-Mail address already subscribed, data: docSnap.data())
          setMessage("E-Mail address already subscribed");
        } else {
          // E-Mail is not yet subscribed
          try {
            const docRef = await setDoc(doc(db, dbName, docId), {
              createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
            });
    
            alert("Thank you for subscribing, you will receive all news and updates to " + values.email);
          } catch (e) {
            // Error adding document
            setError("Failed to subscribe. We're sorry there was an error.");
          }
        }
      };
```

**Security rules:**

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /newsletterSubscribers/{subscriberId} {

      allow get: if true;
      allow list: if false;
      
      allow create: if true;
    }
}}
```